# How can i display my array of obejct on the other method

Tags: java

How can I display my array of object on the other method? I dont know the code. It gives me garbage value or somehow like an address. I used different approach but still garbage value or something `@dasfas`

```
public class Student {


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        menu();
    }

    public static void menu(){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int choice;
        do{
        System.out.println("CMPE 325 Student Record Holder System");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        System.out.println("1.Add Student");
        System.out.println("2.View Records");
        System.out.println("3.Update Students");
        System.out.println("4.Get Average");
        System.out.println("5.Exit");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
        choice=input.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 1):

You must implement [toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) in your Student class.

```
public class Student {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return firstName + " " + lastName; // And so on.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare a method `toString` in the class you want to display:

```
public String toString() {
     // Return some string that will represent the object>
     return this.getFirstName(); // For example
}
```

**Edit:**

For example, if you want to print `Student2` objects inside of `Student` class.:

- You must declare a `toString()` method like the above one in the `Student2` class.
- Then in the `Student`class you can display it like

---

```
Student2 st = new Student2();

... set attributes...

System.out.print(st);
```

Comment: can u give me a sample code? i really don't get it. I've tried dat but the display is still @fdfsasf or @435fdf..@ christian